# Unique_ptr auto destruction magic

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

**From** : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

**Question** : Why did close() gets called only if fp is not NULL?

```
  std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(&std::fclose)> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt", "r"),
                                                        &std::fclose);
  if(fp) // fopen could have failed; in which case fp holds a null pointer
    std::cout << (char)std::fgetc(fp.get()) << '\n';
```

**Comment below the block** : // fclose() called here, but only if FILE* is not a null pointer
    // (that is, if fopen succeeded)

**Question** : How did this happen? I know that calling close(NULL) is bad. So where did the check happen? How did decltype(&std::fclose) know to check for null? What if for some other time calling it even on null is desirable and handled by the function?

Comment: Bad. Missed it. Will try deleting the question.

Comment: Leave the question, is well asked and may help someone else.

Comment: The question uses unspecified/undefined behavior (will be made explicit in C++2a, see https://wg21.link/p0551 revision >=3), because it takes the address of a function in the standard library. This not allowed for almost all functions in the standard library (they might have additional overloads in an implementation and/or different signatures with additional parameters that have default arguments). Only calling such functions is permitted. You need to provide a deleter struct (or from C++2a on a lambda) calling fclose(). This could also do the null check.

Comment: Or wait for unique_resource becoming standardized (https://wg21.link/p0052 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements for [unique_ptr::~unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr) require it to compare `get()` with `nullptr` and only call the deleter if it's not null.

If calling your deleter on `nullptr` is desirable, your application is atypical and probably not suited to using a `unique_ptr`. You cannot modify this behavior.

Comment: Not desirable, but maybe the function handles the nullcheck instead of the callee.  I could probably write a wrapper over unique_ptr maybe if I really wanted to.

Comment: Technically, `unique_ptr::~unique_ptr` checks if the pointer value is not the same as default-constructed deleter's pointer type. So you could supply your own pointer type that default-constructs to a value that will never match any real pointer value, including nullptr.

Comment: @RustyX IMHO, your comment contradicts the answer in a very interesting and relevant way. If you have a source, you should post it as an answer; I'll definitely upvote if your source is legit.

Comment: @RustyX Not to mention, if you are correct, someone should submit a change to cppreference!

Comment: @RustyX, I'm curious too.

Comment: @RustyX 1. [The standard depicts a comparison against `nullptr`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr#single.dtor-2) for the destructor. 2. An implementation can also compare against `pointer()`, which is a value-initialized `pointer`, not default-constructed. 3. It can do that because [`pointer` must satisfy `NullablePointer`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr#single-3), which, among other things, [requires comparing against `nullptr` and against `pointer()` to be equivalent](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/nullablepointer.requirements#tab:nullablepointer).

Comment: I had something like **[this](http://rextester.com/WWZK7189)** in mind, but given the wording in the standard (thanks @T.C.) it's more of a hack than a solution. Indeed it doesn't work in clang because clang does extra checking that `deleter::pointer` is in fact a pointer type. So just give it up, after all it's easy to just create a custom unique pointer.